# Jekyll, Liquid: using `default: "...", allow_false: true` throws an error

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll I'm trying to use the `default` filter, but allowing it to be false. In [the documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/e9b649b3455c63859f1b865a8684607d6ff5b050/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L429) it says you can use the `allow_false: true` parameter. However, when I use this, the Jekyll output shows and error:

```
Liquid error (.../_includes/room_header.html line 7): wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) included  (Liquid::ArgumentError)
```

That line is:

```
{% assign showNameToggle = include.showNameToggle | default: true, allow_false: true %}
```

I tried the (almost) exact line from the documentation, but same error:

```
{{ include.name | default: "No Name", allow_false: true }}
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [commit you're referring to](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commit/f1d62978efe60e7b326a9f2ca5eeac7b39fc56ea) has not been released yet.

It was committed on **`Oct 8, 2019`**.
The [latest version](https://rubygems.org/gems/liquid/versions/4.0.3) was released on **`March 12, 2019`**.

To use unreleased code, you can point your Gemfile to the repository:

```ruby
# Gemfile

# Use code from the default branch (`master`) of the GitHub repository
gem 'liquid', github: 'Shopify/liquid'
```

---

*CAUTION! Use unreleased code at your own risk. It is generally unstable and may result in unexpected results.*

Comment: Oooh! That explains. I guess I'll make my own filter that supports this then, and use their code from that release. That way I don't have to deal with using all unstable code. Thanks!